Querying List<LocalDate> with Spring Boot JPA fails for multiple rows, but works for one row? No converter found capable of converting
According to JPA 2.2 Support for Java 8 Date/Time Types JPA supports LocalDate.
Querying a single row, everything works perfectly fine. But when querying multiple rows somehow JPA is not able to convert it to List.
I'm on the newest spring version 3.3.0
Error Log:
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?
>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<java.time.LocalDate>] for value
 [[...]]


Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of
converting from type [java.sql.Date] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
java.time.LocalDate]

    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound
(GenericConversionService.java:294)

TestEntity.java
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TEST_DATE", columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate testDate;

    // Setter Getters omitted for readability
}

TestRepository.java
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT TEST_DATE FROM TEST_ENTITY", nativeQuery = true)
    LocalDate findBy();
}


TestRepositoryList.java
public interface TestRepositoryList extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT TEST_DATE FROM TEST_ENTITY", nativeQuery = true)
    List<LocalDate> findBy();
}

TestApplicationTests.java
    // this works perfectly fine
    @Test
    void testFindBySingle() throws InterruptedException {
        testRepository.save(new TestEntity(1L, LocalDate.now()));
        log.info(String.valueOf(testRepository.findBy()));
    }

    // this fails
    @Test
    void testFindByList() {
        testRepositoryList.save(new TestEntity(1L, LocalDate.now()));
        testRepositoryList.save(new TestEntity(2L, LocalDate.now()));
        log.info(String.valueOf(testRepositoryList.findBy()));
    }


The native query of findByQuerySingle(id) has no parameter. Probably if you add 2 rows and call  findByQuerySingle(id) it should fail ... You should use findById, spring data will try to match "Query" to a member of the entity.

@PeterMmm Thanks for the hint, but this is not the issue. I edited the code example. Now it should be more clear.

And if you try it with a normal jpa query?

It is well known problem that Spring some times complains about convertors when we use native query. Let's not discuss why it happens and concentrate on how we can manage it. The problem is that we want to get not all fields from entity but only a part of them. This case is called "projection". It is similar to using database view instead of select * from table. There are several solution but I like solution where DTO used as interfaces. Let's begin. We create DTO as interface with specific annotations
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "TestEntityDTO.getTestDate",
        query = "SELECT TEST_DATE FROM TEST_ENTITY",
        resultSetMapping = "Mapping.date")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping.TestEntityDTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = TestEntityDTO.class,
                columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "date")}))
public interface TestEntityDTO {

    LocalDate getTestDate();

}

and modify our repository
public interface TestRepositoryList extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    List<TestEntityDTO> findBy();

}

Note we moved query to DTO annotation
Now let's write a test
    @Test
    void testFindByList() {
        testRepositoryList.save(new TestEntity(1L, LocalDate.now()));
        testRepositoryList.save(new TestEntity(2L, LocalDate.now()));
        testRepositoryList.findBy().forEach(
                e -> System.out.println(e.getTestDate())
        );
    }

The result is
2024-06-07
2024-06-07

You can read more about projection in spring doc and in this nice article
https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/

Spring Data JPA supports java time and its only converts the results to type if the @Query with JPQL and if we use @Query(value="", nativeQuery=true) it will fail to convert the results.
For Ex.,
Fails
@Query(value = "SELECT TEST_DATE FROM TEST_ENTITY", nativeQuery = true)
List<LocalDate> findBy();

Works
@Query("SELECT te.testDate FROM TestEntity te")
List<LocalDate> findBy();

